# Get local variable after function call in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I have a function in python that change my account password. That is something like follows :

```
def f(account):
    new_password = # Some random string generation
    # Do something and send password change request to remote
    account.password = new_password
    account.save()
```

In the second line of above function I send a post request to change my password and then do some processing and finally save my new password. In the processing phase some error has occurred, but unfortunately my request has been sent to server. I have called the function in python shell and now my password has changed but I don't have it. Is it possible to get `new_password` variable from my function in python shell?

Comment: No. The function has ended and all its local variables are gone.

Comment: But you could try looking in the `account` object. Use `x.password` where `x` is the argument you gave when calling `f()`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that is not valid Python code. Functions are not defined with `function`, but with `def`. (It seems you updated your question after reading this).

If indeed the function is called with an `account` object, then the caller will have access to it after the call. So `account.password` should have the password, unless `account.save()` wiped it out.

For instance, this could work:

```
def f(account):
    new_password = # Some random string generation
    # Do something and send password change request to remote
    account.password = new_password
    account.save()

account = Account()  # do here whatever you do to get an account object
try:  # Trap errors
    f(account)
except:
    print("Something went wrong...")
finally:  # Whether an exception occurred or not, print the password
    print("The password is:", account.password)
```

Again, this can only provide the password if `account.save()` did not destroy the value assigned to `account.password`.

If you can change the `f` function to your needs, then include the error handling inside that function and have it *return* the password:

```
def f(account):
    new_password = # Some random string generation
    # Do something and send password change request to remote
    account.password = new_password
    try:  # Trap errors
        account.save()
    except:
        print("Something went wrong...")
    return new_password

account = Account()  # do here whatever you do to get an account object
new_password = f(account)  # now you will have the password returned
print("The password is:", new_password)
```

If however you *already* called the function and the program ended, then it is of course too late now. You must take the necessary precautions before running the code, and only run it when you are sure you can recover the password whatever happens.